# Swift: Store data from Firestore sub collection where uid = uid into an object

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I'm trying to store data retrieved from my Firestore database into an object. My database has a collection of users, and each user has a collection of classes. I want to be able to get the logged in users collection of classes and store them in an array of objects. Most of what I've tried so far can pull data but it won't save it into anything because its able access the data from within the completion handler. Any help would be great, here's the code I'm working with rn:

```
db.collection("users").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: uid).addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            if error == nil && querySnapshot != nil {
                let docId = querySnapshot?.documents[0].documentID
                db.collection("users").document(docId!).collection("classes").addSnapshotListener { (querySnap, error) in
                    guard let documents = querySnap?.documents else{print("No Classes");return}
                    var imageData:UIImage?
                    retrievedClasses = documents.map { (querySnap) -> UserClass in
                        let data = querySnap.data()
                        if let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: data["class_img"] as! String, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters){
                            imageData = UIImage(data: decodedData)
                        }
                        return UserClass.init(name: data["class_name"] as! String, desc: data["class_desc"] as! String, img: imageData!, color: data["class_color"] as! String, link: data["class_link"] as! String, location: data["class_location"] as! GeoPoint, meetingTime: data["meeting_time"] as! Dictionary<String,String>)
        
                    }
                    print(retrievedClasses[0].printClass())
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need to do something like this:

```
func getUserClasses(for userID: String, completion: @escaping (Result<[UserClass], Error>) -> Void) {
    db.collection("users").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: userID).addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        if error == nil && querySnapshot != nil {
            let docId = querySnapshot?.documents[0].documentID
            db.collection("users").document(docId!).collection("classes").addSnapshotListener { (querySnap, error) in
                guard let documents = querySnap?.documents else {
                    print("No Classes")
                    completion(.failure("No Classes"))
                    return
                }
                let retrievedClasses = documents.map { (querySnap) -> UserClass in
                    let data = querySnap.data()
                    var imageData: UIImage?
                    if let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: data["class_img"] as! String,
                                              options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) {
                        imageData = UIImage(data: decodedData)
                    }
                    let user = UserClass(name: data["class_name"] as! String,
                                         desc: data["class_desc"] as! String,
                                         img: imageData!,
                                         color: data["class_color"] as! String,
                                         link: data["class_link"] as! String,
                                         location: data["class_location"] as! GeoPoint,
                                         meetingTime: data["meeting_time"] as! Dictionary<String,String>)
                    return user
                }
                completion(.success(retrievedClasses))
            }
        } else {
            completion(.failure("Request Error"))
        }
    }
}
```

Then you will able to use data after request completion:

```
getUserClasses(for: "123") { result in
    switch result {
        case .success(let allClasses):
            retrievedClasses = allClasses // retrievedClasses is a property in your class which you are going to use  
            if !retrievedClasses.isEmpty() {
                print(retrievedClasses[0].printClass())
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: So sorry, bit new to swift here, how would I call this? Currently I have it in a separate class but can move it to wherever. Trying to use it to populate an array of userClass objects. I notice when I call it I have some code to write in the completion block

Comment: retrievedClasses should be observable object (model) so View  can update UI when model updates.